# XPath and PHP: Parse from the nth instance of an element

Tags: php, xpath

Assuming I have just used an XPath query to get the 5th instance of the `book`element in a sample xml file that looks something like this:

```
<books>
<book id=1></book>
<book id=2></book>
<book id=3></book>
...etc
</books>
```

How can I get the next 10 `book`elements after the one I've just queried? I'm using PHP and XML DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
following-sibling::book[position() <= 10]
```

Comment: Does he need to use the current node as the context like: `$xpath->query('following-sibling::book[position() <= 10]', $currentBookNode);`?